# Syntax error in MySQL query : 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I've got a problem with my SQL query. I've been trying to extract some data from SQL but it seems that I've failed somewhere and I can't locate it

```
SELECT user_comments.*, 
    users.ID AS user_ID,
    users.username AS user_username,
    profiles.userID AS profiles_ID
    INNER JOIN users ON users.username = user_comments.author 
    INNER JOIN profiles ON profiles.userID = users.ID
    WHERE user_comments.img_id = 'b75962591b38b117b45d'
```

And the error is

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'INNER JOIN users ON users.username = user_comments.author 
>                       INNER JOIN prof' at line 5

Comment: ** FROM user_comments** is missing before first join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `FROM user_comments` ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `FROM` clause in your query. I am assuming the missing table is **user_comments**

```
    SELECT user_comments.*, 
    users.ID AS user_ID,
    users.username AS user_username,
    profiles.userID AS profiles_ID
    FROM user_comments
    INNER JOIN users ON users.username = user_comments.author 
    INNER JOIN profiles ON profiles.userID = users.ID
    WHERE user_comments.img_id = 'b75962591b38b117b45d'
```

Answer (score 1):

ur forget to add

```
from user_comments
```

try this

```
SELECT user_comments.*, 
    users.ID AS user_ID,
    users.username AS user_username,
    profiles.userID AS profiles_ID
    from user_comments
    INNER JOIN users ON users.username = user_comments.author 
    INNER JOIN profiles ON profiles.userID = users.ID
    WHERE user_comments.img_id = 'b75962591b38b117b45d'
```

Answer (score 1):

Add "FROM" Clause to your SQL query,